# In Rstudio when auto-indenting (ctrl+I) function definitions, function arguments get indented with two tab spaces. How can I set it to one tab space?

Tags: r, rstudio, auto-indent

In RStudio, I am having trouble properly aligning function arguments when using the auto-indent tool (ctrl+I). The resulting function definitions either end up vertically misaligned or with too many spaces before each argument. I want just one tab space before each argument.

Here are the current outcomes when adjusting `vertically_align_arguments_indent`:

- Output 1: Using `rstudioapi::writeRStudioPreference("vertically_align_arguments_indent", FALSE)`

```
MyFunction <- function(
    arg1,
  arg2,
  arg3
) {
  # stuff 
}
```

- Output 2: Using `rstudioapi::writeRStudioPreference("vertically_align_arguments_indent", TRUE)`

```
MyFunction <- function(
    arg1,
    arg2,
    arg3
) {
  # stuff 
}
```

Instead, I would like the auto-indent tool to produce the following output:

```
MyFunction <- function(
  arg1,
  arg2,
  arg3
) {
  # stuff 
}
```

Can someone suggest the correct RStudio settings to achieve my desired output?

NB: I cannot solve this just by setting the tab spacing to be shorter. If I do it the body of the function will keep on being unaligned with the arguments.

Comment: Hello, I will see if I can work out your desired indentation, but it may be a deliberate choice - I believe their 'house style' is to have the first argument on the same line as the opening `(` then indent further arguments to align with the first.

Comment: I can't access it from here, so may not be useful, but there's an issue on github that appears relevant from the preview.  https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/10752

Comment: Thank you. It seems that they acknowledge the fact that many users might not want that (I would as far as saying most of them) but then they didn't act on the issue, apparently. See here https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/11101